# how to parse JSON string using JSON.parse()

Tags: javascript, json

```
{
"elements":[{
        "content":{
            "xyz-media:game":{

                "display_name":"Pool Practice",
                "enable_video_ad":true,

            }
    },
    {
        "content":{
            "xyz-media:game":{

                "display_name":"Bouncing Balls: Christmas Edition",
                "enable_video_ad":true,

            }
    },

    ]  
}
```

How do i parse this JSON String? I have been trying this for last 2 days without any luck. Below is the code that I have been trying.

```
//where r.responseText is the Response from URL
messages = JSON.parse(r.responseText);

//To access the display_name of first content
messages.elements[0].content[0].display_name
```

Please tell me where am i going wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Elements` is an array of `maps` . That is element[0] is a map with one of ther keys as `content` and the value of `content` is a map again, So there isn't any `elements[0].content[0]`. You access it as `element[0]["content"]` or `element[0].content` but note there is no `[0]` for content, as it is not an array, and you proceed so on to access other values.

Comment: To access `display_name` : `elements[0].content["xyz-media:game"].display_name;`